# Why is first HttpClient.PostAsync call extremely slow in my C# winforms app?

Tags: c#, winforms, dotnet-httpclient

I have an httpclient like this :

```
var client = new HttpClient();
```

I post to it like this:

```
var result = client.PostAsync(
                endpointUri,
                requestContent);
```

And get the response like this:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = result.Result;
```

I understand this call will block the thread, thats how its supposed to work (just building a tool for myself, no async threads needed)

The first time I run this call, it takes about 2 minutes to get a result.  Meanwhile, if I do the exact same call elsewhere its done in 200ms.  Even if I hit google, it takes 2 minutes.  But, after the first call, as long as I keep the app open any additional calls are good.  Its just the first cal when I open the application.  What could be causing this?

Comment: I would start by using `.ContinueWith` instead of `.Result` (of use `async/await`...) - aside from this I see nothing that could cause that delay and to be honest I suspect that the problem lies somewhere else

Comment: This would be easy if we had a stack to look at. Use new WebClient().DownloadString() for testing purposes, pause the debugger during the pause and post the call stack including external code. It probably says something about DNS or proxy.

Comment: I can't begin to guess but I would start by ruling out the possibility that doing it synchronously is the problem. HttpClient was designed to be async only and there are strong warnings about using it in a blocking fashion. `await result` is just as easy as `result.Result` so why resist using it correctly?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The problem was that it was hanging for a very long time trying to resolve a proxy for the client. Initializing the HttpClient like this did the trick:

```
var client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseProxy = false
            });
```

Comment: Thx a lot for the answer. I had the same problem for Get requests.

Comment: I'm having similar issues, a request that takes 40ms on the second attempt and measured by fiddler takes 1-2.5 second (which considering the length of the request is very big) for the first time even with a new instance of HttpClient. Setting UseProxy = false didn't help.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, even with proxy = false, it is very slow at first time and fast after the first within a minute. Just for a specific url, others not. Anybody have another suggestion. @TimothyGonzalez

Comment: I've the same problem, nybody can help us ?

Comment: Been busting my head with this one for a while. Anyone solved it? @Marinpietri any luck? Setting proxy to false did not solve the problem for specific URL but the endpoint is responding instantly when testing in postman.

Comment: Hi, in my case the problem was on api service. The code was correct, but the host where the service was staying,  seem to me dont response to request IPV4

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was trying to access a service on `localhost`. Apparently the HTTP client tries to connect to the IPv6 localhost first before connecting to its IPv4 equivalent (source: https://github.com/jchristn/restwrapper), which causes slowdown.

Changing `localhost` to `127.0.0.1` in my case cut off 2000ms of delay, although there is still maybe ~120ms delay on the first request.