# c# postAsync very slow even after setting UseProxy = False

Tags: c#, dotnet-httpclient

I am facing a problem where the first postAsync request is taking 20seconds to complete. All subsequent requsts execute with no delay.

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler{UseProxy = false});
//async function
StringContent stringContent = new StringContent(jsonString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
var result = await client.PostAsync(url, stringContent);
string response = await result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

I've done the same request in postman on the same computer, and it completes with no delay. Made curl on another computer, also completes with no delays. Further, C# postAsync is slow againts a particular endpoint, not all endpoints in general. I manage the endpoint and have done nothing to slow down the response.

I have already checked this answer and it doesn't solve the issue: [Why is first HttpClient.PostAsync call extremely slow in my C# winforms app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35084773/why-is-first-httpclient-postasync-call-extremely-slow-in-my-c-sharp-winforms-app)

After placing log messages at the very beginning of the server side script, I can also confirm that the request does not recieve endpoint until roughly 20s has passed. Again, this all happens only on first request.

**Update**: same is true for GET request using `getAsync`
**Update 2**: wireshark shows no requests for endpoint IP until ˜20s has passed.

What could be the problem? Tested with .NET 4.6.1 and 7.2

Comment: A previous version of the same question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/45175147/11683 (no answer).

Comment: You are [using the same instance](https://www.aspnetmonsters.com/2016/08/2016-08-27-httpclientwrong/) of HttpClient, aren't you?

Comment: @GSerg I do, but the same happens without recycling. First request with instance1 is slow, the second with a instance2 is normal.

Comment: What about using Diagnostic Tools in VS to see the difference between the call stacks? That should give you a good idea what's taking so long https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/diagnostic-tools-debugger-window-in-visual-studio-2015/

Comment: Another: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39708448/11683